# How to install Sensu client without installing Sensu server?

Tags: monitoring, sensu, process-monitoring, process-monitor

I am trying to install a Sensu client without the server.

According to the [documentation](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/sensu-on-ubuntu-debian#sensu-core):

"The Sensu Core package installs several processes including `sensu-server`, `sensu-api`, and `sensu-client`."

However after adding the repository, I was only able to locate the aggragate `sensu` package and could not locate or install `sensu-client`.

I noticed [a ticket on github](https://github.com/sensu/sensu/issues/628) stating it was not possible however that was 2 years ago so maybe things have changed?

Is it possible to install Sensu server without having to install Redis, RabbitMQ and Sensu server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sensu package will install sensu-server, sensu-api, and sensu-client services, you can however, setup a functional sensu-client without installing Redis, RabbitMQ, and without configuring sensu-server.

```
sudo yum install sensu
vi /etc/sensu/config.json 
vi /etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json
sudo /etc/init.d/sensu-client start
sudo /sbin/chkconfig sensu-client on
```

/etc/sensu/config.json should at least have the rabbitmq location of the server, while /etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json of course needs to have the ip and name of the client.

Comment: Can your please post the config.json and client.json

Answer (score 0):

If someone facing an error with installation provide by @Enrique  `sudo yum install sensu`

```
https://sensu.global.ssl.fastly.net/yum/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

The above was not working on aws ec2 linux.

They can try this to add sensu repo.

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/sensu.repo
```

Add this

```
  [sensu]
name=sensu
baseurl=http://sensu.global.ssl.fastly.net/yum/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

then install sensu

```
sudo yum install sensu -y
```

Remaining steps same as answerd by @Enrique Arriaga

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with sensu core. But you can install it using  the new product from sensu, sensu go which has sensu backend (replaces sensu server) and sensu agent (replaces sensu client) allows to install only sensu agent on your infrastructure.